Is there a shortlist of ideal languages for a legal contract, or could such a thing be made?
I've been studying English, Spanish, Japanese and Ancient Greek for several years now. English and Japanese are my two strongest languages. I noticed that when comparing these two, there seems to be a preponderance of words in English, in particular, which mean a vast number of things, depending on the context. Sometimes, even within a single context, numerous meanings are possible. By comparison, Japanese seems to have far more words that are very specific in meaning, or limited in the contexts in which they can be used.
This got me thinking about contract law. Incredible hoops and hurdles are taken in order to make the language used in English contracts as specific and limited as possible, sometimes at the cost of it's understandability, and sometimes, ironically, at the cost of it's reliability. Would not a contract written in a language like Japanese come, from the beginning, with far fewer inbuilt loopholes?
And if a reasonable case can be made for this, doesn't that imply that there are indeed languages which are superior in specificity, if not in flexibility (you won't catch me complaining about the flexibility of English in the context of poetry, but you might hear me complain about the obscurity you encounter in Japanese when you try to be flexible and poetic with it)?
Finally, if some languages are, indeed, more specific by nature than others, could this not be researched, categorized, and finally, ranked? Has such a thing been done, and I'm just too new to the field to know about it yet?

There is no such thing as an ideal language for contracts. People draw up contracts in whatever language they speak and use. You wouldn't use a contract in  English in, say, Spain. It's not legal for use in courts, etc.

You may be interested in the language of Yélî Dnye. According to the linked grammar, in this language sequences of words may have arbitrary meanings that are independent of the individual words they consist of, or the meaning of the whole cannot be split into a sequence of individual parts.

The disambiguation comes from the whole assemblage, and this suggests another kind of analysis in terms of gestalts - no parts have meaning independent of the whole: it is the whole that conveys the meaning. [...] A gestalt analysis of this sort suggests that [Yélî Dnye] has partially lexicalized its syntax, by letting strings of words convey arbitrary meanings.

